# Is there any way to hide a checkbox's parent div upon clicking it, with pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, hide

I have this example: http://dabblet.com/gist/540b8d498447aaea159fa4215d18984f which gets me close.

I'd like for the click of the "I'm a Toggle" to hide itself and the top green box.

Is this possible without Javascript?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016, there is no way to select the parent of an element in CSS. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1384214).